# Bourne Shell Script

Tags: sh

I'm attempting to write a script in the Bourne shell that will do the following:

1. Read in a filename
2. If the file does not exist in the target directory, it will display a message to the user stating such
3. If the file exists in the target directory, it will be moved to a /trash folder
4. If the file exists in the target directory, but a file of the same name is in the /trash folder, it will still move the file to the /trash directory, but will attach a _bak extention to the file.

My use of the Bourne shell is minimal, so here's what I have so far. Any pointers or tips would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
#!/bin/sh
#Scriptname: Trash Utility
source_dir=~/p6_tmp
target_dir=~/trash
echo "Please enter the filename you wish to trash:"
read filename
if [ -f $source_dir $filename]
    then mv "$filename" "$target_dir"
else
    echo "$filename does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Do not read the filename as input; take filenames as arguments instead.

Comment: Your back up thing is sort of ridiculous. What if there is *another* file with the `_bak` extension?

Comment: `if [ -f $source_dir $filename ]` would expand to `if [ -f ~/p6_tmp SOME-FILE ]`. It should expand to `~/p6_tmp/SOME-FILE`. For this, you can try using `if [ -f ${source_dir}/${filename} ]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use `~` to refer to `$HOME` in a `sh` script. Switch to `$HOME` (or change the shebang to a shell which supports this, such as `#!/bin/bash`).

To refer to a file in a directory, join them with a slash:

```
if [ -f "$source_dir/$filename" ]
```

Notice also the required space before the terminating `]` token.

To actually move the file you tested for, use the same expression for the source argument to `mv`:

```
mv "$source_dir/$filename" "$target_dir"
```

As a general design, a script which takes a command-line parameter is much easier to integrate into future scripts than one wich does interactive prompting. Most modern shells offer file name completion and history mechanisms, so a noninteractive script also tends to be more usable (you practically never need to transcribe a file name manually).

Comment: I'm not going to write the `_bak` part but here is some inspiration for a slightly different approach: https://gist.github.com/tripleee/f085ae3d4b7650b33c67

Comment: Thank you so much, Tripleee! This board and people like yourself have been an absolute godsend to a programming-challenged person like myself.

Comment: You're welcome; and good luck. See however also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126180/is-it-acceptable-to-write-a-thank-you-in-a-comment

Comment: I would gladly vote up comments, but I do not yet have enough reputation to do so (and I'm not sure why people are voting down my questions).

Answer (score 0):

A Bash Solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
source_dir="~/p6_tmp"
target_dir="~/trash"
echo "Please enter the filename you wish to trash:"
read filename
if [ -f ${source_dir}/${filename} ]
then
    if [ -f ${target_dir}/${filename} ]
    then
        mv "${source_dir}/${filename}" "${target_dir}/${filename}_bak"
    else
        mv "${source_dir}/${filename}" "$target_dir"
    fi
else
    echo "The file ${source_dir}/${filename} does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: You need to double-quote all file names.  This will inhibit tilde expansion, though.  I would suggest to remove the double quotes from the initial assignments to fix that, or use `$HOME` instead of a tilde.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the completed script. Thanks again to all who helped!

```
#!/bin/sh
#Scriptname: Trash Utility
#Description: This script will allow the user to enter a filename they wish to send to the trash     folder.
source_dir=~/p6_tmp
target_dir=~/trash
echo "Please enter the file you wish to trash:"
read filename
if [ -f "$source_dir/$filename" ]
then
    if [ -f "$target_dir/$filename" ]
    then mv "$source_dir/$filename" "$target_dir/$(basename "$filename")_bak"
    date "+%Y-%m-%d %T - Trash renamed ~/$(basename "$source_dir")/$filename to ~/$(basename    "/$target_dir")/$(basename "$filename")_bak" >> .trashlog

    else mv "$source_dir/$filename" "$target_dir"
    date "+%Y-%m-%d %T - Trash moved ~/$(basename "/$source_dir")/$filename to ~/$(basename "/$target_dir")/$filename" >> .trashlog

    fi
    else
    date "+%Y-%m-%d %T - Trash of ~/$(basename "/$source_dir")/$filename does not exist" >>  .trashlog
    fi
```